# click to insert all images html tag to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site will be show some images.

These images's class is `class="insert_img"`

I need a Button onclick to insert to a textarea(my editor).

How to get the all `<img class="insert_img">` src attr?

Comment: what do you want to insert into the editor **exactly** ?

Comment: And where did you get stuck? What went wrong with your own attempt(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i couldnt understand what you are asking, but it looks like this is what you are looking for:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#BT_Insert").click(function(){
        $(".insert_img").each(function(id,val){
            console.log($(val).attr("src"));
            $("#editor").val($("#editor").val()+"\n"+$(val).attr("src"));   
        });
    });
    
});
```

```css
#editor{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" class="insert_img"></img>
<img src="http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/so-images/stackexchange.png" class="insert_img"></img>
<br/>
<button id="BT_Insert">Click Me</button>
<hr/>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```